# Trying to compare dates in DataView.RowFilter

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataView with 2 date fields, which are the days where a camping beggins and ends.

The user introduces a year via textBox, and I want a filter that returns only those campings that:

1.Begin on that year

OR

2.End on that year

OR

3.Begin before that year AND end after that year

So for example, if i have a camping that begins on 2018 AND ends on 2021, this camping should be returned when user searches for years 2018, 2019, 2020 or 2021.

Now, the code I have to do so is as follows:

```
 string x = String.Format(

 "Convert(begin_date, 'System.String') LIKE '*/{0}*' " +
 "OR " +
 "Convert(end_date, 'System.String') LIKE '*/{0}*' " +
 "OR " +
 "(begin_date < #{1}# AND end_date > #{2}#)",
 yearFilter_textBox.Text,
 new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(yearFilter_textBox.Text), 1, 1).ToShortDateString(),
 new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(yearFilert_textBox.Text), 12, 31).ToShortDateString());

 campingsDataView.RowFilter = x;
```

The resulting string of this a little bit messy code is as follows:

```
 Convert(begin_date, 'System.String') LIKE '*/2019*' OR Convert(end_date, 'System.String') LIKE '*/2019*' OR (begin_date < #01/01/2019# AND end_date > #31/12/2019#)
```

The idea of this code is that I apply the first two conditions by converting date field on DataView to string, and then I use the operator LIKE to check that the year on that date is the same one than the introduced by user. This works fine and the problems is not here.

The problem is on applying the third condition. For that, I just want to compare the dates fields with the first and last days of the year introduced by user. Now, this throws a FormatException (string can't be recognised as a valid DateTime value).

As far as I know, you can compare dates on a RowFilter using this ShortDateTimeString format, so I don't know why I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

suggestion make use of linq to datatable it make your task easy

```
var filter = testTable.AsEnumerable().
                       Where(x => x.Field<string>("begin_date").Contains( "2019") || 
                                  x.Field<string>("end_date").Contains( "2019"));
```